# Angular Http request body not binding to .net core webapi primitive parameters

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

My angular http request body params are not binding to my api. This is my api which Iam trying to bind body directly without using any complex parameter like class.

```
public async Task<Object> RejectRequest([FromBody] int RequestId, string 
Reason){
}
```

This is my angular http request:-

```
 rejectRequest(data): any {
 var body = JSON.stringify(data);
 const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
  }),
  responseType: 'text' as 'text'
 };
 return this.http.post('/api/Dashboard/RejectRequest',body, httpOptions)
}
```

my body request is :-

```
{
 "requestid":"45",
 "reason":"dfgsdf"
}
```

Comment: your api method is httpget ... in angular you use httppost

Comment: how you understood my api is http get?

Comment: as request body

Comment: `{
 "requestid":"45",
 "reason":"dfgsdf"
}`

i have attached json in question.

iam getting it binded if iam using models in api as params.

but if direclty used primitive params i cant get it binded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that, from UI you sending JSON object as body but in API you receiving it as 2 different parameters.

If you are sending parameters using httpParams from ui you can bind it to api using [FromQuery]

So here you can add a new model in API and change your API method as shown below,

```
public class MyClass
{
     public string RequestId { get; set; }
     public string Reason { get; set; }
}

public async Task<Object> RejectRequest([FromBody]MyClass MyObj){
   //Your code...
}
```

Comment: I have tested with that and it will work.
but since there is only two params that why i didnt added any classes.
can u help me on what chnages i need to make on angular for making this work

Comment: @AmeerPappay as you mentioned [FromBody] in API, you can't send an object like how you sending from UI. Instead of [FromBody], make it [FromUri] ([FromQuery] if you are using .net core) and send it as parameter from UI instead of body

Comment: how can i send this `var body = {
 "requestid":"45",
 "reason":"dfgsdf"
}` as multiple param rather than passing that var body

Comment: @AmeerPappay are you  trying to send it as httpParams ?

Comment: No, as request body.

if iam using it to sent as body then i must bind it as model in web api?

Also if iam using httpparams then i cant bind using [FromUri]?

Iam i right now?

Comment: @AmeerPappay correct.. but still you can send it as parameters but its good habit to send it as a model.

Comment: but i dont know why, its not working with string data type.
it changed when i stringfy my body request

Comment: @AmeerPappay Don't stringify if you using model in API.